# " ***stack smashing detected***: <unknown> terminated" on choosing an object

Tags: game-engine

Blender 2.79b in ArcoLinux 19.01.4:

Upon choosing an object, Blender terminates, with 
" ***stack smashing detected***:  terminated"
Any ideas about what may cause this problem?

Comment: Well, clearly it is a bug, so trying to get around it will not be good. Try to use older versions and, if possible, report the issue to developers at Blender site.

Comment: closed as off-topic by Ray Mairlot, Duarte Farrajota Ramos, Scott Milner, m.ardito, David♦ Feb 3 at 14:33: Sorry guys, I thought the info was relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've learned much. I wanted to report a bug, and on the website, one of the suggestions was to download the newest version before reporting a bug, so I downloaded 2.79.7. When I opened my project and selected an object, Blender still crashed, but it rewarded me with new information...as I remember, the information said something about sRBG display not supported, defaulting to "NONE.", and I needed to check my User Preferences file. I looked through the User Preferences thoroughly several times, but found nothing relating to sRBG or any choices regarding that. So I downloaded 2.78c, which still supported sRBG, evidently, because when I selected an object, it didn't crash.
Joel Gomes da Silva was correct with his answer about using older versions, but curiosity and stubbornness prevailed, and I learned a lot. Thank you Joel!